# Android - Questions about System-UI

Tags: java, android, system

So I was looking at the settings in CM10.1(4.2.2) and I saw an option to change the color of the softkeys using a color picker.

Now i'm working on an app and though doing something like that would be cool. But I don't understand how it does it. How does it change the color using code, and why doesn't it require a reboot?

Also, could I use a similar process to change the Colorado of the wi-fi inside my app as well? How would one do this. I am interested in how you can do this, as it would make a great addition to my app.

I saw I wasn't the only one wondering this, and I think this is a good question. If someone could, can you maybe explain what could be going on, and then explain how I could do it, and maybe give me a link to some code to take a look at?

Anything would help. I'm curious, but baffled. I think an answer could help not just me, but many others. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to create many themes for user and let them choose at runtime ? If yes, then there are so many links regarding it.

Comment: Use my simple project https://www.dropbox.com/s/cdmgadwef7m5wpf/ChangeTheme.zip

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't using the public SDK.

Long answer: This is not a feature of stock AOSP. Cyanogenmod is a heavily modified version of Android, and features like this are implemented at a ROM level, not an app level. If you want to include this feature, you'll have to customize Android at a source level and build a system image for each and every device you want it on.

([Source - Google Employee](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/wroaPcuqmRM))